# Is login required is available for class based view in Django?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I cant use the login required in class based view in django rest frame work

How can i authenticate backend in django rest frame work

Answer (score 1):

Here the doc has specified the method for authentication. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/